# how to increase the width of the images

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi in the below code how to increase the width of the images as well as how to remove the border of the slider div it's showing white border I want to remove the border.
By using javascript I am displaying images in slide show format but it's not increasing the width.as well as I want to remove the img border.

**html**

```
<div id="sliders1">
      <div id="slider">
      <div class="gallery">
        <ul class="images">
          <li class="show"><img width="950" height="300" src="img/1.jpg" alt="photo_one" /></li>
          <li><img width="950" height="300" src="img/2.jpg" alt="seascape" /></li>
          <li><img width="950" height="300" src="img/3.jpg" alt="seascape" /></li>
          <li><img width="950" height="300" src="img/4.jpg" alt="seascape" /></li>
          <li><img width="950" height="300" src="img/5.jpg" alt="seascape" /></li>
          <li><img width="950" height="300" src="img/6.jpg" alt="seascape" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

**css**

```
#slider {   
  width: 950px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
} 
ul.images {
  width:1050px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;

} 
#sliders1{
    background-color:#00008B;
}
ul.images li {
  position:absolute;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  list-style:none;
}

ul.images li.show {
  z-index:500;  
}

ul img {
  border:none;  
}
```

**js**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-1.5.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('ul.sf-menu').sooperfish();
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: @mplungjan sorry it's 950px

Comment: Post the JS you are using please.

Comment: @JoeCorby see my js file

Comment: Are you sure there isn't more JS somewhere? I'm guessing your using jquery.sooperfish.js

Comment: @JoeCorby yes I am using that libray

Comment: You should not write inline size of image but css

Answer (score 0):

For the borders of the slider, modernizr add a margin to the body element. Adding

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

should be enough to solve your problem.

I did not understand what you want to do with the images.

Comment: without understanding how to gave the answer

Comment: there is one question for the slider and one for the images, no ?